# What is the use of parameter passed in join() in java?

Tags: java, concurrency

According to Java Docs, if t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing then,

`t.join();` causes the current thread to pause execution until `t's thread` terminates.

So, what does `t.join(2000)` mean?

Does it mean that the current thread would wait for a maximum of 2 seconds before killing `thread t` and wouldn't wait for `thread t` to terminate by itself?

Comment: Javadoc should be one of the first things you learn.

Comment: Here's the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yea i went through javadocs, i couldn't find the explanation for parameters passed in join()

Comment: @Takendarkk thanks for the link, sorry for asking such silly question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, what does t.join(2000) mean?

As per [documentation- `Thread.html#join(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29).

> Waits at most millis milliseconds for this thread to die. A timeout of
>   0 means to wait forever.

And

> Does it mean that the current thread would wait for a maximum of 2 seconds before killing thread t and wouldn't wait for thread t to terminate by itself?

It will wait for die but it will not kill the threa for which it is waiting for.

Comment: execution will remain

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have one more doubt here, if i use `t.join(0);` then the current thread would wait forever even after `thread t` terminates or it will wait indefinitely till `thread t` terminates

Comment: `t.join(0)` is same as `t.join()`

Answer (score 1):

A call to `t.join(2000)` will return when thread `t` to dies or 2 seconds have passed, whichever comes first. Calling `join()` will never kill a thread.

Answer (score 0):

it means Waits at most mentioned milliseconds for this thread to die. timeout 0 milliseconds  means the thread will wait forever.

Answer (score 0):

`t.join(2000)` means that it will wait for the thread to die for a maximum of 2000 milliseconds. ([Ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):